# In Firefox, the right edge on the dropdown button on selectboxes with padding is disappearing on hover

Tags: css, firefox

In Firefox, if I have a selectbox with padding-top and padding-bottom set to 3px, I get a dropdown button of which the right edge will disappear when I hover over it.

[image]

Why?

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select
{
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BeVN/)

Comment: In my firefox its working fine!

Comment: give some right and left padding on it `padding:3px 2px;`

Comment: It reproduces on FF `29.0.1` here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select{
   padding-top: 3px;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
   color: #555555;
   display: block;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 34px;
   line-height: 1.42857;
   transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
   vertical-align: middle;    

 }
```

Comment: Not a lot of explanation here! I never had rounded borders on the selectbox I started with, so it has a low degree of problem description correlativity as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes

```
select{ 
     padding:3px 1px;
}
```

please have a look. hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not explain the behavior of the select-box :)

Answer (score 0):

When we render a 'select' element without any css it is exactly the same as when we render a select element with 1px padding on all sides. Which means by default a select has a padding of 1px on all sides. 
When we increase or decrease the padding property, we have to ensure to add the 1px right padding to maintain the default padding.

I used photoshop to measure the height and width to confirm the dimensions.

I created a fiddle to demonstrate this theory. Hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/2BeVN/

So a padding-right: 1px seems to be required.

```
select{padding-top: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;padding-right: 1px}
```

Comment: Why do I have to do that?

Comment: But if I do not set padding-right, only padding-top and padding-bottom, should not padding-right already get its default value?